# Java. Execute a class from other class?

Tags: java, class

I'm very new in Java and I have a small question. I believe it is due to some misunderstanding of the concepts.

So, I have main class menu:

```
/**
 * menu.java
*/
public class menu {
    public void run() {
        println ("1. Option#1.");
        println ("2. Option#2.");
        println ("============");

        int choose = readInt("Enter a choice:");
        if (choose == 1) {
        // QUESTION>>>>>   // ### how can I call class option1.java here?

    }
}


/**
 * option1.java
*/
public class option1 { 
   public void scriepedos () { 
        setFont("Times New Roman-24");
        while (true) {
                String str = readLine("Please enter a string: "); 
                if (str.equals("")) break; 
                String rev = reverseString(str); 
                println(rev);
        }
    }

    private String reverseString(String str) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i=0; i<str.length();i++){
            result=str.charAt(i)+result;
        }
        return result.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance. Leo

Comment: You *can* call the *instance* method of class by creating an object via *Object* reference.

Comment: You can call method of the class, you cann't call class

Comment: Thank you! I know it's a conceptual problem...

Comment: The question it is in code block.

Comment: but the new problem it is that nothing happened when I call the instance method. This is because "scriepedos" it's void ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an *instance* of option1 to call upon e.g.

```
option1 o1 = new option1();
o1.scriepedos();
```

Alternatively you can make the method `static`. That means that you don't need the corresponding instance of the object e.g. in `option1.java`

```
public static void scriepedos () { ...
```

then in `main.java`

```
option1.scriepedos();
```

The above isn't very OO. You're now making use of the fact that you can have an object encapsulating state etc. and is a much more procedural style.

Notes:

1. I suspect you need a [public static void main()](http://www.roseindia.net/java/gettingstartedwithjava/public-static-void-main.shtml) method to invoke the above
2. Java style would require class names to be camel-cased. e.g. `Option1`, `Main`

Comment: Thank you all! About notes: 1. I realy have but I simplify the code :); 2. Thats are not my real class name :), but Thank you!

Comment: I do it but nothing it's happened when I call the instance option1.scriepedos(). This it's because scriepedos is "void" type ?

Answer (score 1):

You can not call to class. You have to create new object of class and call it's methods like below :

```
Option1 op1 = new Option1();
// call any Option1 method
op1.scriepedos();
```